# Azure policy definitions as code: avoiding duplicate parameter definitions

Tags: azure, json, azure-policies

I'm looking to create a number of Azure policies using infrastructure as code.

The [MS Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/policy-as-code#create-and-update-policy-definitions) advises a structure as below:

```
.
|
|- policies/  ________________________ # Root folder for policy resources
|  |- policy1/  ______________________ # Subfolder for a policy
|     |- policy.json _________________ # Policy definition
|     |- policy.parameters.json ______ # Policy definition of parameters
|     |- policy.rules.json ___________ # Policy rule
|     |- assign.<name1>.json _________ # Assignment 1 for this policy definition
|     |- assign.<name2>.json _________ # Assignment 2 for this policy definition
|  |- policy2/  ______________________ # Subfolder for a policy
|     |- policy.json _________________ # Policy definition
|     |- policy.parameters.json ______ # Policy definition of parameters
|     |- policy.rules.json ___________ # Policy rule
|     |- assign.<name1>.json _________ # Assignment 1 for this policy definition
|     |- assign.<name2>.json _________ # Assignment 2 for this policy definition
|
```

This makes sense, but all examples of policy definitions I've seen include the parameter definitions; so I don't see the value in having the separate `policy.parameters.json` file if it's just duplicating information.

### Question

Is there a way to avoid this duplication; e.g. by having the `policy.json` file refer to the `policy.parameters.json` file instead of copying its content, or is there some value added by having this duplication?

(The same scenario occurs for the rules file; I assume the answer for that section would be the same...)

### Example of this duplication

From the Azure Community Policies repo:

[Policy File](https://github.com/Azure/Community-Policy/blob/master/Policies/Tags/add-date-created-tag/azurepolicy.json#L25-L32) includes these lines:

```json
"parameters": {
  "tagName": {
    "type": "String",
    "defaultValue": "DateCreated",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Tag Name",
      "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'Date'"
    }
  }
}
```

[Parameters file](https://github.com/Azure/Community-Policy/blob/master/Policies/Tags/add-date-created-tag/azurepolicy.parameters.json#L1-L10) exactly duplicates the content found under the above parameters section above (well almost; in this case the description differs slightly, but that feels like a mistake rather than a justification):

```json
{
  "tagName": {
    "type": "String",
    "defaultValue": "DateCreated",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Tag Name",
      "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'DateCreated'"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: (Submitted an issue to the MS Docs team to see if they can clarify this approach: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/74184)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the [MS Docs team](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/74184):

> The structure is partially to help with some of the SDK functions that
> take those components as a standalone file. For example, in Azure CLI
> the command for creating a policy assignment, az policy assignment
> create, uses a params (or p) parameter that expects a JSON string or
> path of just the parameter node. While you could add extra steps in
> your pipeline to shard the "core" file that has this information, the
> team felt it was a cleaner path to have each file used as part of the
> source.